# @Configuration equivalent to <aop:config expose-proxy="true" />?

Tags: spring

I migrate a Spring project from XML-based configuration to Java-based configuration.

What is the best way to migrate the following piece of configuration?

```
<aop:config expose-proxy="true" />
```

Hint: I use this setting to access the proxy in a bean so that a transactional method can be called from a method that is not transactional.

Hint: I have seen https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8148 but I don't know whether the second of the recommended approaches is the right one.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-10454) created for this as an improvement. I would suggest voting for it to get more chances to be prioritized better.

Comment: It is fixed in version 4.3.1.RELEASE. Finally!